Unable to install any distros under WSL / Hyper-V
I have a newer machine that previously ran VMs without any issue, trying to install WSL and run Ubuntu and it fails, I think WSL might be hosed anyway and tried to reinstall.  All updates installed.  Installed latest BIOS firmware.  Checked all virtualization settings in BIOS, etc. and they're enabled.  Error indicates there's virtualization is not enabled or that the hypervisor is not running:
Here is a screenshot - https://i.imgur.com/Xz7okKY.png (can't link w/o reputation.)
I ran SFC / DISM as well.  Attempting to install VMWare now.

If you're going to use VMWare then this question doesn't make sense.

I'm just attempting another hypervisor as this seems to be Windows misidentifying BIOS settings.  Able to install Ubuntu w/o issue via VMWare.  Would prefer to just run it under WSL instead of using all of this bloat.

You can't have both, for starters, and that likely is what caused the error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install  and understand ther difference WSL WSL2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions My comment above was because if you aren't going to troubleshoot WSL then why would we waste time with your question?

I understand they can't run simultaneously, I installed it to verify that it was Windows misidentifying virtualization options in the BIOS.  I would prefer to just run it under WSL.  It was never installed beforehand, I've used Hyper-V in the past on this same machine.

You cannot start the WSL VM through Hyper-V manager. It’s not a Hyper-V VM. You also can’t start it with VMWare

Did you enable Virtual Machine Platform like the error says?
